# PHP write to text file from input

Tags: php, web

I have the following code

```
<div id="mailbox">
  <form action="verification.php" method="post">
  <input placeholder="Enter your email" type="mail" name="name" style="width:270px; 
   height:42px; border: solid 1px #c2c4c6; font-size:16px; padding-left:8px;" />
</div>
<div>
  <form action="verification.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" id="button2" value="Next" />
</div>
```

I want if a user put an input in the enter your email placeholder - it will save the input into a text file.

I have no idea what code I need to write in verification.php. I have 2 days knowledge in PHP.

I want every input a user put in the form, will be saved to user.txt file on my machine.

Thank you

Comment: can we see your verification.php.?

Comment: verification.php does not exist yet since I don't know how to store data in it :)

Comment: PHP write file from input to txt not working for me.. as I said I am really new to PHP

Comment: So please come back when you have studied a little more. Visit the PHP site

Comment: Go to more questions and make stupid comments just to get more badges so you can feel good about your self

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

First change your HTML to:

```
<div id="mailbox">
  <form action="verification.php" method="post">
    <input placeholder="Enter your email" type="mail" name="name" style="width:270px; height:42px; border: solid 1px #c2c4c6; font-size:16px; padding-left:8px;" />
    <input type="submit" id="button2" value="Next" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Then, **verification.php** (make sure you have all error reporting on)

```
<?php
if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    echo 'Data received, writing to file <br/>';
    if (!file_put_contents('/path/to/filename', $_POST['name']."\n", FILE_APPEND)) {
        echo 'Sorry! unable to write to the file specified';
    } else {
        echo 'data written to file';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kamrul,Thanks for the tip in the HTML! I've edited verification.php to look like:
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    file_put_contents('/var/www/html/users.txt', $_POST['name']."\n", FILE_APPEND);
}

But still not working

Comment: did you get any error ?

Comment: Hi, nope, blank page

Comment: can you confirm if you have error reporting `on` from your php configuration ? apache needs to have permission in the directory you specified.

Comment: Hi,

I've changed verification.php to:
`<?php
if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    file_put_contents('/tmp/mydata.txt', $_POST['name']."\n", FILE_APPEND);
}`

Also, i've checked in PHP.INI that display errors is On.
Still blank page and no data written into /tmp/mydata.txt

Comment: Also, i've chown -R apache:apache the specific folder

Comment: I dont see why it wont work. please try my update, that will give you a better idea.

Comment: Warning: file_put_contents(users.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/verification.php on line 9
Sorry! unable to write to the file specified

Comment: ok, so now you know what the issue is right ?

Comment: Thanks for the help Kamrul :)